# How to override minus operator in Array Ruby

Tags: ruby

Let's say i have two classes

car class

```ruby
class Car
  include Comparable
  attr_reader :wheel

  def initialize(wheel)
    @wheel = wheel
  end
end
```

big car class

```
class BigCar
  include Comparable
  attr_reader :wheel, :big_car

  def initialize(wheel)
    @wheel = wheel
    @size = ["big", "truck", "monster"].sample
  end
end
```

generate array of them

```
cars = []
4.times do |x|
  car = Car.new(x)
  cars << car
end

big_cars = []
3.times do |x|
  big_car = BigCar.new(x)
  big_cars << big_car
end
```

i want to do

```
cars - big_cars
```

then i want it to result 1 car left, because it 4 - 3 = 1

but instead of 1, it returns all car.

i want to minus operator compare the `wheel` variable between two array.

so i add method in `Car` class

```
  def <=>(other)
    car.wheel <=> other.wheel
  end
```

but it does not works.

What's the right way to do it?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the docs of [`Array#-`](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.0/Array.html#method-i-2D):

> items are compared using `eql?`

By including `Comparable` and implementing `<=>`, you only get `==`, but not `eql?`. You have to add the latter yourself, e.g. as an [`alias`](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.0/syntax/miscellaneous_rdoc.html#label-alias) for `==`:

```
class Car
  include Comparable
  attr_reader :wheel

  def initialize(wheel)
    @wheel = wheel
  end

  def <=>(other)
    self.wheel <=> other.wheel
  end

  alias eql? ==
end
```

Note that in order to get `Array#-` working, you just need `eql?`, i.e. a reduced version could look like this: (without `Comparable`)

```
class Car
  attr_reader :wheel

  def initialize(wheel)
    @wheel = wheel
  end

  def eql?(other)
    self.wheel == other.wheel
  end
end
```

With both of the above, you'd get your expected result:

```
cars     = Array.new(4) { |x| Car.new(x) }
big_cars = Array.new(3) { |x| BigCar.new(x) }

cars - big_cars
#=> [#<Car:0x00007fd0908cd710 @wheel=3>]
```

You probably want to implement `eql?` for `BigCar`, too. Or maybe make `BigCar` a subclass of `Car` and inherit its methods.

Comment: how to add multiple comparison in` <=>` method?. for example i add `steer` instance variable on each class and change  `<=>` method definition to `self.wheel <=> other.wheel && self.steer <=> other.steer`
but seems does not work

Comment: @pujidjayanto `Comparable` is intended for objects that can be _ordered_. Can you explain how `wheel` and `steer` affect the ordering of your cars?  If the attributes are _not_ related to ordering, you might want to implement `eql?` in a different way, for example `def eql? ; self.wheel == other.wheel && self.steer == other.steer ; end` (note that `self.` is optional)

Comment: hmm i do not have any intention for ordering now, i just want to substract two array with condition that i state in question (comparing by wheel and steer) @Stefan

Comment: @pujidjayanto updated with a simpler variant

Comment: Hi, <=> operator returns 1,0,-1, yes? while it returns 1 or 0 or -1 how does this statement person1>person2 or something like that gets true or false?

Comment: @Rajagopalan `Comparable` defines the comparison methods like `>` based on `<=>`. If `<=>` returns a result greater than 0, `>` returns `true`.

Answer (score 3):

As `cars` is an array, then the method you should be looking at is [`Array#-`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Array.html#method-i-2D).

You could create a new class that holds cars without making a distinction whether they're big or not, just so they can be compared by their `wheel`.

```
class Cars
  attr_reader :cars

  def initialize(cars)
    @cars = cars
  end

  def -(other)
    cars.each_with_object([]) do |car, arr|
      other.cars.each do |another_car|
        arr.push(car) if car.wheel == another_car.wheel
      end
    end
  end
end

big_cars = 3.times.map { |n_of_wheels| BigCar.new(n_of_wheels) }
# [#<Car:0x00007f92171ab750 @wheel=0>, #<Car:0x00007f92171ab6b0 @wheel=1>, #<Car:0x00007f92171ab688 @wheel=2>, #<Car:0x00007f92171ab660 @wheel=3>]
cars = 4.times.map { |n_of_wheels| Car.new(n_of_wheels) }
# [#<BigCar:0x00007f92171ab598 @wheel=0, @size="truck">, #<BigCar:0x00007f92171ab3b8 @wheel=1, @size="monster">, #<BigCar:0x00007f92171ab110 @wheel=2, @size="truck">]
Cars.new(big_cars) - Cars.new(cars)
# [#<BigCar:0x00007f92171afb48 @wheel=0, @size="monster">, #<BigCar:0x00007f92171af9b8 @wheel=1, @size="monster">, #<BigCar:0x00007f92171af8c8 @wheel=2, @size="truck">]
```

You don't really need the new class, you could just use the body of `Cars#-` extracting the variables it depends on.

And the method name doesn't necessarily have to be `-`, it can be any other (like `diff`, `difference`, `compare_by_wheels`, etc). It just gives a quick idea on what it does.

Answer (score 1):

For your first question you want to compare the lengths of those arrays, which would look like this

```rb
cars.length - big_cars.length
```

because length gives you the number of items in the array.

Regarding the second Question, could you explain the expected output?